# Using output in another module or resource

Tags: terraform

I've seen a good amount of posts that talk about passing a module's output into another module. For some reason I can't get this to work.

I can get the output of the module without any issues

> ```
> $ terraform output
> this_sg_id = sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ```

However, when I call the module in the resource or into another module, it asks me for the Security group ID.

> ```
> $ terraform plan
> var.vpc_security_group_ids
>   Security Group ID
>   Enter a value:
> ```

Here's my file structure:

> ```
>  ── dev
> │     └── service
> │       └── dev_instance
> │           ├── main.tf
> │           ├── outputs.tf
> │           ├── variables.tf
> ├── modules
> │       ├── ec2
> │       │   ├── build_ec2.tf
> │       │   ├── outputs.tf
> │       │   └── variables.tf
> │       └── sg
> │           ├── build_sg.tf
> │           ├── outputs.tf
> │           └── variables.tf
> ```

Not sure if this is correct but in dev/service/dev_instance/main.tf:

> ```
> module "build_sg" {
> source         = "../../../modules/sg/"
> vpc_id         = var.vpc_id
> sg_name        = var.sg_name
> sg_description = var.sg_description
> sg_tag         = var.sg_tag
> sg_tcp_ports   = var.sg_tcp_ports
> sg_tcp_cidrs   = var.sg_tcp_cidrs
> sg_udp_ports   = var.sg_udp_ports
> sg_udp_cidrs   = var.sg_udp_cidrs
> sg_all_ports   = var.sg_all_ports
> sg_all_cidrs   = var.sg_all_cidrs
> }
>
> module "build_ec2" {
> source                         = "../../../modules/ec2/"
> vpc_security_group_ids     = ["${module.build_sg.this_sg_id}"]
> }
> ```

In dev/service/dev_instance/output.tf:

> ```
> output "this_sg_id" {
> description = "The security group ID"
> value       = "${module.build_sg.this_sg_id}"
> }
> ```

My ec2 module build_ec2.tf file has the following:

> ```
> resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
> vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.build_sg.this_sg_id}"]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `var "vpc_security_group_ids"` defined somewhere, I assume in one of your `variables.tf` files. Terraform doesn't automatically know to fill that in with the output from a module. You need to remove the `var` definition and just use the module output reference in your template.

Variables are used to pass in values from the command line. They are not tied to module outputs in any way. If you expect values to come from a module you are using then you should not be also defining that value as a variable.

Answer (score -2):

I also think, you need to remove var definition from your variable tf file and use only module output reference.